# Booting into emergency mode

Tags: boot, uefi

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 -- or trying to. After some major reconfiguration that involved removing Windows and installing SuSE Leap 16.1, my Kubuntu goes into emergency mode on boot.  I think it only needs a very simple fix, but I haven't been able to find it. Here are some relevant pieces of information:

1. I have an EFI partition on `sda11/etc/stab` which is confirmed by fdisk.
2. /etc/fstab contains an entry `UUID=E8C2-65DB /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1`. It also contains a comment that `/boot/efi` was on `/dev/sda12` during installation.
3. `/` is correctly mounted on `/dev/sda6`.

So what are the magic words?

The message I get is:

```
You are now in emergency mode.  After logging in, type "journalctl xb" to view system logs, "systemctl default or "exit" to boot into default mode".
Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue):
```

Pressing Enter gets me a (root) command prompt; anything else just gives me the same message again.

Comment: Can you please add the messages that appears on your screen when you enter the emergency mode ?

Comment: Parsa, I've added that information to the question.